# How fix position of UIPageControl ? Fix it always on top when page is changing with PageViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uipagecontrol

I'm made on-boarding screen with PageViewController for sliding and ReviewViewController as ViewController for content.

Every time when i slide a page I create new ReviewViewController with right content inside.

On ReviewViewController I've got Image, Label and PageControl

Everything works good But - when I slide a to the next page - PageControl slide out like image or label, but I want to fix it and change only color.

One more time - when i slide every elements slide out, I want to fix PageControl always on the same position on the screen

Please give advise.

[image: Image of my StoryBoard]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using a container view. Rather than making the `UIPageViewController` the `rootViewController` of your `UINavigationController`, add an intermediate `UIViewController` that has a container view subview, and add the `UIPageControl` as a sibling.

You should remove the `UIPageControl` from your sub view controllers.

You'll need to add some way of propagating page updates back to the UIPageControl - a delegate protocol or closures will work nicely for this.

[image]

Comment: Thats good idea, but tell me please - how could I set constraints for UIPageControl if all of my elements at the another one VC? Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: That sounds like a different question. Please attempt this yourself, and if you can't figure out the answer, ask another question.